# Connecting react Js site on S3 with Node JS Backend on ECS using ApplicationLoadBalancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I have multiple front end application built on react JS with webpack 5.
Backend consists on multiple microservices built on Node JS/express, deployed on ECS.

I’m currently using EC2 Application Load Balancer with listener on port 80 for http.
I’m trying to use ALB on https by using SSL certificate from AWS certificate manager.

The client website could not retrieve data back end.

How do I use the same SSL certificate on the S3 sites ?

Answer (score 0):

To use the same SSL certificate on S3 sites that you are using on your application load balancer, you will need to place CloudFront in front of the S3 sites, change your domain DNS record(s) to point to CloudFront, and configure CloudFront with the SSL certificate.

Comment: Thank you Mark. Thats what I thought when reading AWS documentation. I just have to shutdown my current domain server to use with the cloudfront via route 53

Comment: I don't think you need to switch to Route53 for this. Route53 isn't a requirement for using CloudFront.